# Google Chrome showing different behaviour for CORS with authorization header for different web apps

Tags: google-chrome, http, cors

For one of my websites, I am trying to allow CORS to my localhost and I am getting following error in `Google Chrome Version 112.0.5615.137 (Official Build) (x86_64)`

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8088/examplepath' from origin 'https://abc.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

I can also see a very nice explanation presented in Google Chrome Issues panel.

```
A cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) request was blocked because it contained request headers that were neither CORS-safelisted (Accept, Accept-Language, Content-Language, Content-Type) nor allowed by the Access-Control-Allow-Headers response header of the associated preflight request.
To fix this issue, include the additional request headers you want to use in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers response header of the associated preflight request.
1 request
Request Status  Preflight Request   Disallowed Request Header
 xxx    blocked 
 xxx    authorization
```

In the Preflight request's response, Chrome requires that the server needs to send `Authorization` as a specified header instead of a wildcard. I am able to resolve this issue by sending `"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "authorization"` instead of `"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*"`.

---

But I found that I have similar functionality on my other web app which has the same domain but with a different subdomain `https://xyz.example.com`, On this web app the same functionality works without specifying the `authorization` header in the localhost app's preflight response. I do get the following warning though when it works,

```
Deprecated Feature Used
Authorization will not be covered by the wildcard symbol (*) in CORS Access-Control-Allow-Headers handling.
1 source
52:0
```

[image: Authorization will not be covered by the wildcard symbol (*) in CORS Access-Control-Allow-Headers handling.]

For simplification, I created a simple localhost nodejs app. But still, the behavior remains the same, on one subdomain Preflight request works without the `authorization` header on the other it does not work.

Why chrome is behaving differently here? Any pointers will help. Both `https://xyz.example.com` and `https://abc.example.com` are sending the same preflight request, I checked that by printing the request details in the sampel localhost app.

Here is my small nodejs app, i have written so that localhost webapp logic does not come into the picture.

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 8088;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  const headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://xyz.example.com", // works
    // "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://abc.example.com", // does not work
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
    "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "*",
    "Access-Control-Max-Age": "999"
  };
  console.log(req.method + req.url + " " + JSON.stringify(req.headers))
    
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.writeHead(204, headers);
    res.end();
    return;
  }

  // res.statusCode = 200;
  res.writeHead(200, headers);
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Comment: @Rob fixed that. Added image, so that people can understand the issues panel that i am talking about.